# Auto increment a number field in mongoose model

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, auto-increment

I was using MySql DB for my website and now updating it to MongoDB. There were columns in some tables getting auto-incremented and I want to make sure that the same continues.

Below are my finding so far but none is working.

Using **mongoose-auto-increment** plugin

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    Schema = mongoose.Schema,
    autoIncrement = require('mongoose-auto-increment');
 
var connection = mongoose.createConnection("mongodb://localhost/myDatabase");
 
autoIncrement.initialize(connection);

EmborderSchema.plugin(autoIncrement.plugin, {
  model: 'Emborder',
  field: 'emborder_id',
  startAt: 28855,
  incrementBy: 1
});
```

Using pre save hook:

```
EmborderSchema.pre('save', function (next) {
  if (this.emborder_id == undefined) {
    Emborder.findOne({})
      .sort({emborder_id: -1})
      .exec(function (err, data) {
        this.emborder_id = data.emborder_id + 1;
        next();
      })
  } else {
    next();
  }
});
```

Using the first method gives me an error

> E11000 duplicate key error collection: 24hd.24hd_emborder index: emborder_id_1 dup key: { 23345 }

Second method gives this error

> E11000 duplicate key error collection: 24hd.24hd_emborder index: emborder_id_1 dup key: { : null }

Note: emborder_id was the primary key in my old Mysql DB and in this code value of emborder_id is undefined as I am adding a new record.

Please help me finding whats going wrong in this approch.

Comment: Can you add what `data` print in second approach inside `exec` block.

Comment: So the issue was with **this**. The second solution worked if I assign  **this** to a variable as @Himanshusharma did. As it goes into exec functions the  **this** reference is changed and I was getting null error.

Comment: Yes the issue was with this. Mark the nswer if you gget the solution.

Comment: Reason to this is `Emborder.findOne({})` has his own scope and refering to `this` inside that leads to `Emborder` scope . So if we take `this` in variable `self` . It work fine.

Answer (score 2):

I will recommend second approach for you.

```
EmborderSchema.pre('save', function (next) {
  var self = this;
  if (self.emborder_id == undefined) {
    Emborder.findOne({})
      .sort({emborder_id: -1})
      .exec(function (err, data) {
        if(!data.emborder_id){
         self.emborder_id = 1;
         next();
        }else{
          self.emborder_id = data.emborder_id + 1;
          next();
        }
      })
    next();
  }
});
```

For more you can read about `Context` in javascript.

**For example**, inside of a function, when you say: “this.accoutNumber”, you are referring to the property “accoutNumber”, that belongs to the object within which the function is executing.

If the object “foo” has a method called “bar”, when the JavaScript keyword “this” is used inside of “bar”, it refers to “foo”. If the function “bar” were executed in the global scope, then “this” refers to the window object.

Context example taken from --> https://blog.kevinchisholm.com/javascript/difference-between-scope-and-context/